# Specifying AppCmd arguments with single quote

Tags: windows, iis, web-hosting, windows-server-2016, web

I'm attempting to configure a site in IIS on Windows 2016 using appcmd.exe.  Specifically PHP and FastCGI.  I'm running into an issue where specifying the arguments parameter with single quotes fails.  I can't seem to figure out how to escape this or what incantation of quotes is required.  Here's the command the does work:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webServer/fastCGI /+"[fullPath='c:\php\php-cgi.exe', arguments='-d open_basedir=E:\Web\www.example.com;E:\Sessions\www.example.com;E:\Logs\www.example.com;E:\Temp\www.example.com', maxInstances='0', instanceMaxRequests='10000']" /commit:apphost
```

With open_basedir on Windows I need

```
-d open_basedir=E:\Web\www.example.com;E:\Sessions\www.example.com;E:\Logs\www.example.com;E:\Temp\www.example.com
```

to be enclosed in single quotes.  Like this:

```
-d open_basedir='E:\Web\www.example.com;E:\Sessions\www.example.com;E:\Logs\www.example.com;E:\Temp\www.example.com'
```

If I create the FastCGI application first without arguments, I can add them afterwards like this:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webServer/fastCGI /[fullPath='c:\php\php-cgi.exe'].arguments:"-d open_basedir='E:\Web\www.example.com;E:\Sessions\www.example.com;E:\Logs\www.example.com;E:\Temp\www.example.com'" /commit:apphost
```

This issue is that I can't change additional settings afterwards because I can't specify the single quoted path with appcmd.

I can accomplish this with the IIS Manager GUI and via C# code.  So it's definitely possible to set it this way.  I just can't seem to get the correct format for appcmd.

Comment: AppCmd.exe is a legacy program, have you considered using PowerShell to configure IIS?  You can also try to use `Configuration Editor` in the GUI to make your changes and then have a look at the generated AppCmd command using the `Generate Script` dialog.

Comment: I realize it's older, but it's still supported as far as I can tell.  It's also scattered through many scripts in the organization.  I didn't really want to rewrite everything in PowerShell.  FWIW, appcmd has the same single quote issue on 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

You use two single quotes to indicate a single quote in a string, for example

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webserver/httpProtocol /+"customHeaders.[name='Content-Security-Policy',value='default-src ''self'';']"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran across your question while trying to find the same answer. I discovered a workaround and wanted to let you know.

Use the XML i/o feature of appcmd.exe. On a site with the proper headers, run appcmd list config /section:httpProtocol /xml > addheaders.xml and save the output file. 
On another system, you can run appcmd set config /in < addheaders.xml

I'm sure you can find a way to include the xml inside the script if you don't want to rely on an extra file.